# How to toggle/untoggle slide while updating class in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Hi I'm new to VueJS and I'm trying to achieve the following thing :

I have a table that is closed and I want to deploy it on click and revert the sign on the triggering button.

So far I've only managed to make it suddenly pop-up on click but had no luck with any kind of transition or changing content...

I've made a JSFiddle with everything I've done so far : https://jsfiddle.net/p5z7skqa/

Javascript, CSS and HTML :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#cart-app",
  data: function () {
    return {
      opened: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openRecap: function() {
      this.opened = !this.opened
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.cart-app {
  width: 100%;

  &.open {
    height: auto;
  }
}

.cart-app-mobile-up {
  align-items: center;
  background: blue;
  border-top-left-radius: 90px;
  border-top-right-radius: 90px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto -2px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 70px;
}

.cart-app-sticky {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="cart-app" class="cart-app cart-app-sticky " :class="{'open': this.opened}">
  <div :class="{'open-cart-recap': this.opened}" class="cart-app-mobile-up" @click="openRecap()">&bigtriangleup;</div>
  <div class="cart-app-title">Récapitulatif de votre commande</div>
  <div class="cart-app-combinations" v-if="opened">
    <ul class="cart-app-combinations-title list-unstyled">
        <li>Produits</li>
        <li></li>
        <li class="text-right">Taille</li>
        <li class="text-right">P.U.</li>
        <li class="text-right">Qté</li>
        <li class="text-right">Prix HT</li>
        <li class="sr-only">Actions</li>
    </ul>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>test2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Main issue I got with the transition part is that, it was either going the wrong way or no animating the movement of the trigger button.

Any help would be gladly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a few issues here, but the main one is that you are using `v-if`. If you inspect element, you'll see that it doesn't exist. So you can't animate it exactly. A vue transition may work, although the other issue is that you can't animate the property auto as simply as that. I'd recommend looking at something like https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/transition-to-height-auto-with-vue/

Comment: I tried using ```<transition>``` but I still had issues targeting the proper element to animate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple CSS transition like :

https://jsfiddle.net/2rveky7u/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#cart-app",
  data: function () {
    return {
      opened: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openRecap: function() {
      this.opened = !this.opened
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.cart-app {
  width: 100%;
}

.cart-app-mobile-up {
  align-items: center;
  background: blue;
  border-top-left-radius: 90px;
  border-top-right-radius: 90px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto -2px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 70px;
}

.cart-app-sticky {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(calc(100% - 85px));
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.cart-app-sticky.open {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.cart-app-title {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cart-app-combinations-title {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 600;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="cart-app" class="cart-app cart-app-sticky " :class="{'open': this.opened}">
    <div :class="{'open-cart-recap': this.opened}" class="cart-app-mobile-up" @click="openRecap()">&bigtriangleup;</div>
    <div class="cart-app-title">Récapitulatif de votre commande</div>
    <div class="cart-app-combinations">
      <ul class="cart-app-combinations-title list-unstyled">
          <li>Produits</li>
          <li></li>
          <li class="text-right">Taille</li>
          <li class="text-right">P.U.</li>
          <li class="text-right">Qté</li>
          <li class="text-right">Prix HT</li>
          <li class="sr-only">Actions</li>
      </ul>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>test1</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>test2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test5</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```